# Avoid Cookie Expiration (Web Scraping)

Tags: python-3.x, cookies, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests

So I am using Python to make a web scraper for my school's gradebook website called Schoology. So far, it works great, but I was troubled to see that all of the cookies will expire in a few days. Is there a way to automatically get new cookies so that I dont have to replace them every few days? My school uses an "SSO" login where you have to login with your school google account which makes things sort of complicated. I used CURL to get the header/cookie information. If there is anything else that I can improve on in my code, let me know. Here is my code:

```
# Schoology Web Scraper

import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

grades = []

headers = {
    # A bunch of headers / cookies that will expire
}

response = requests.get('https://monongalia.schoology.com/grades/grades', headers=headers)
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, 'html.parser')

for item in soup.find_all('span', attrs={"class":"course-grade-value"}):
  grades.append(item.get_text())

print('\n'.join(grades))
```

Comment: You will need to automated the login and retrieval of the cookies in your script. You have no control over the cookies expiring

Comment: @OzzyWalsh But will I be able to do that with the google login?

Comment: It should be possible. But it is outside the scope of a Stack Overflow answer. If you can do it with curl, you can most likely do it through python.

Comment: Along with Ozzy Walsh's comment, if you go to the Network tab on Chrome's inspect element, start recording a network log, and then log in. You will be able to see where the login form submission goes (path-wise) and with what data goes with it (Username, Password, CSRF-token, etc.)

Answer (score 0):

you can have it go through the sign in and use credentials provided by the user you can use:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

##################

username=""
password=""
schoolID=""

##################

# ^ fill in these values ^

payload = {
"mail":username
"pass":password
"school_nid":
}

session = requests.Session()
response = session.post('https://monongalia.schoology.comlogin/ldap', data = payload)
# this will log you in using the credentials provided above

# continue with script below, all cookies will be saved without you needing to do 
# anything
```

send the username and password as a payload to the url, using Session() it will keep the 
cookies throughout the script so you dont need to manually collect them